# Transforming MongoDB query to Java with $elemMatch

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm having a lot of trouble transforming my MongoDB Query into a Java one.
I've tried both QueryBuilder and DBObject and can't manage to make it work.

This is my MongoDB Query:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection_v2').find({
    idCab:1,
    cab: {
        $elemMatch:{
            idCat: ObjectId("14567823123688")
        }
    },
    fMod: {
        $gte: ISODate("2017-04-04T00:00:000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2017-04-04T23:59:590Z")
    }
})
```

My DBOBject approach has been this and the problem that I get is that I cannot append(object, object) but append(string, object) so I don't know how should I structure it:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(
            "idCab", "1")
            .append( new BasicDBObject(
                "cab", new BasicDBObject(
                        "$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject( 
                                "idCat", categoria ))))
            .append( new BasicDBObject(
                    "fMod", new BasicDBObject( "$gte", fechaInicio )
                        .append( "$lt", fechaFin )
                    )
            );
```

For a QueryBuilder I have this and the problem is that I didn't manage to make the part about the $elemMatch...

```
QueryBuilder query = new QueryBuilder().start().and(
            new QueryBuilder().start().put("idCab").is(String.valueOf(pIdPortal)).get(),
            new QueryBuilder().start().put("fMod")
                .greaterThan(fechaInicio).get(),
            new QueryBuilder().start().put("fMod")
                .lessThan(fechaFin).get();
```

Could you help me, please? I'm going from a 50-50 love/hate relationship with MongoDB to a 100 hate relationship...

Comment: What's the error you're getting? For the DBObject approch, `idCab` should be ant int, and not a String. Also, make sure that `fechaInicio` and `fechaFin` are instance of **`Date`**, and that `categoria` is an **`Objectid`**

Comment: The main problem I'm getting is on the DBObject approach, that I cannot do an append(object, object), it says it has to be append(string, object), and so I don't know how to structure it.

For the QueryBuilder approach my problem is that I don't know how to transform the $elemMatch part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your DBObject is not properly formed. Your trying to pass a `BasicDBObject` as key instead of passing a `String` . 
Just remove the two extra `BasicDBObject` like this :

```
   BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(
            "idCab", 1)
            .append("cab", new BasicDBObject(
                    "$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject(
                            "idCat", categoria)))
            .append("fMod", new BasicDBObject("$gte", fechaInicio)
                    .append("$lt", fechaFin)
            );
```